# A little clarity on getting key values using AngularFire v2?

Tags: firebase, angularfire

Sorry for the length of this but it's driving me a little bit crazy:

Let's say I want to get an item's "title" and ".priority" key values when it loads.

First let's see how every thing's laid out:

```
 $scope.items = $firebase(new Firebase("https://****.firebaseio.com"));

 $scope.items.$on('loaded', function() { 

console.log($scope.items);

});
```

With that we get:

```
> Object {$bind: function, $add: function, $save: function, $set: function, $remove: function…}
    > $add: function (item, cb) {
    > $bind: function (scope, name) {
    > $child: function (key) {
    > $getIndex: function () {
    > $on: function (type, callback) {
    > $remove: function (key) {
    > $save: function (key) {
    > $set: function (newValue) {

    > this is my item: Object
          $$hashKey: "012"
          $id: "this is my item"
          $priority: 2884707
          title: "this is the title of my item"
          __proto__: Object


    > __proto__: Object
```

Looks good,  let's try to grab that $priority:

```
 console.log($scope.items.$child('$priority'));
```

Oops:

```
Uncaught Error: Firebase.child failed: First argument was an invalid path: "$priority". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"
```

Fine, we'll skip that for now and just try for the title:

```
console.log($scope.items.$child('title'));

> Object {$bind: function, $add: function, $save: function, $set: function, $remove: function…}
    > $add: function (item, cb) {
    > $bind: function (scope, name) {
    > $child: function (key) {
    > $getIndex: function () {
    > $on: function (type, callback) {
    > $remove: function (key) {
    > $save: function (key) {
    > $set: function (newValue) {
    > __proto__: Object
```

No title.

Okay, let's try it a different way :

```
    var firstItem = $scope.items.$getIndex()[0];  //returns $ids in order of priority
     console.log($scope.items.$child(firstItem));

     > Object {$bind: function, $add: function, $save: function, $set: function, $remove: function…}
         > $add: function (item, cb) {
         > $bind: function (scope, name) {
         > $child: function (key) {
         > $getIndex: function () {
         > $on: function (type, callback) {
         > $remove: function (key) {
         > $save: function (key) {
         > $set: function (newValue) {
              title: "this is the title of my item"
         > __proto__: Object
```

But now there's no priority!

Kitchen sink swearing at the computer time:

```
 console.log($scope.items.title);

     > undefined

 console.log($scope.items[0].title);

     > Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined 

  console.log(Object.keys($scope.items));     

     > ["$bind", "$add", "$save", "$set", "$remove", "$child", "$on", "$getIndex"]
```

What am I missing?  I can manage to get the 'title' by doing a couple U-turns, (figuring out what the item's $id is using '$getIndex()', grabbing the nth item and then making another call using '$child()' ),  but even that doesn't work for $priority.   Is there an easier way to get key values from within AngularFire v2?  Or any way at all to get the $priority?

Comment: Two things here. The first is that the $child would receive a key of a record, so you'd want to try something like `$scope.items.$child('record1').$priority`. Second, please try upgrading to the [latest/official 0.5 release](https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.5.0/angularfire.js), as Anant just made a couple fixes that might apply here. Report back on your findings if that doesn't help.

Comment: That's the release I'm linking to and  '$scope.items.$child('record1').$priority' gives me 'undefined', which is correct because $priority isn't returned when 'console.log($scope.items.$child('record1'))' is used, as in my "Okay, let's try it a different way" example.  If it's supposed to then that may be a bug.

Comment: I was unclear. The point was that $child operates just like Firebase.child(). angularFire goes to Firebase, calls .child() on the current path, and returns a new $firebase object for that child path. Thus, you can't ask for $child('$priority') because that's not a valid Firebase key. This is not a way to get a child key from an object, but a new synchronized reference to a Firebase path. So child keys would be obtained with `$scope.items['$priority']` or similar (I wrote that incorrectly above--sorry).

Comment: Sorry if I'm misunderstanding but `console.log( $scope.items.$child('the_id').$child('title'))` works correctly but  `console.log( $scope.items.$child('the_id')['$priority'])` returns 'undefined', as does `console.log($scope.items['$priority'])`.  And that's expected because `console.log( $scope.items.$child('the_id'))` does not return $$hashkey, $priority or $id the way `console.log( $scope.items)` does for each object.  Which made me wonder if that's a bug.

Comment: Quite possibly a bug, hard to say because I still don't fully understand. But $child('$priority') will never work, because `$` is not allowed in Firebase path keys. That's the first step to working through this, is understanding exactly what $child does, which is return an entirely new $firebase reference (not just a value for a given key in the data)

Comment: Here you go, a screenshot of my console, I labeled how I'm outputting them right above each object.  http://imgur.com/a/bITwv You can see the second one doesn't contain $priority, and so the third one is undefined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe I am / was experiencing the same issue. Hopefully this is related to your experience. Namely:

```js
$scope.items = $firebase(new Firebase("https://xxxxxx.firebaseio.com"));
$scope.items.$on('loaded', function() {
  console.log($scope.items['some key']); // this writes undefined to console
});
```

What I noticed is that this actually **does work** if I don't rely on the `loaded` event.  E.g in the HTML:

```html
<a href="#" data-ng-click="logItem()">click me</a>
```

and in the JS:

```js
$scope.items = $firebase(new Firebase("https://xxxxxx.firebaseio.com"));
$scope.logItem = function() {
  console.log($scope.items['some key']); // this works
}
```

Clicking on the "click me" link logs my item to the console as expected.

Feels like the collection at `loaded` time isn't fully populated with the underlying items from firebase.

Comment: BTW, I'm now using the pattern as defined in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20610932/2478447).  Turns out while the raw firebase data isn't populated at `loaded` time, it is passed as a parameter the callback function, so you can access it that way if you like.

Answer (score 4):

The `$child` method should only be used to create a *new* AngularFire reference. Calling `$child` is the same as calling `$firebase(new Firebase(parentULR +  "/childName"))`. In your example, if all you are trying to do is to get the `$priority` and `title` for a given object, you can simply do:

```js
$scope.items = $firebase(new Firebase("https://****.firebaseio.com"));
$scope.items.$on('loaded', function() {
  var item = $scope.items['your-item-id'];
  console.log(item['$priority']);
  console.log(item.title);
});
```

If you don't know the ID of your item, you can iterate over the `$scope.items` object to find it if you'd like.

Comment: Thanks, but this is what happens when I do that: http://imgur.com/a/mXePx  (sorry for the image, was the fastest way to show you, I obviously edited out the firebase address but that's it otherwise).

Comment: That's odd, can you console.log($scope.stories)? It should have a bunch of objects in it.

Comment: mlenner up there figured it out, apparently it isn't quite ready $on('loaded'), so all I had to do was use a little $timeout.

Comment: I feel like you shouldn't have to do that though. If the value is `loaded` then really that should act as a callback space. There shouldn't be an additional need to wrap it with a `$timeout`. That or use the value from the callback. Frankly I feel like a callback feels more natural to people anyway. `$scope.items.$on('loaded', function(value) {console.log(value)});`

Comment: Yes this seems like a bug. We should wrap the loaded callback in its own little $timeout.

Comment: This commit should fix it: https://github.com/firebase/angularFire/commit/db7dcfc80ab7b5a6f20ca00ad15382e36f67b778

Answer (score 3):

As you've noted, your examples are a bit fragmented and there's also no example of your data structure to work from. So it's a bit hard to get a strong picture of what you're trying to accomplish. I'm going to make some assumptions below about all of these things and then offer a working example accordingly. If that doesn't answer the question, maybe it'll help us dig in and find the exact use case you're looking for.

Let's assume, for starters, that we have a list of users at kato.firebaseio.com/users, each of which is an object like so:

```
/users/:id/name
/users/:id/email
/users/:id/favorite_dessert
```

Now, let's assume I want to make those work with the following angularCode:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="user in users">{{user.name}} really likes {{user.favorite_dessert}}</li>
</ul>
```

In my controller, I could put something like this:

```
var fbRef = new Firebase('https://kato.firebaseio.com/users');
$scope.users = $firebase( fbRef );
```

Now they will automagically appear in my HTML code.

Now, let's assume that when one of these users is clicked, I want to get a two-way binding, which can be edited in a form like this:

```
<form ng-controller="EditUserController">
      <input ng-model="user.name" type="text" />
      <input ng-model="user.email" type="text" />
      <input ng-model="user.favorite_dessert" type="text" />
</form>
```

Inside `EditUserController` I could obtain the user as follows:

```
var fbRef = new Firebase('https://kato.firebaseio.com/users/'+user_id);
$firebase( fbRef ).$bind($scope, 'user');
```

Or I could use `$child` like this (purely to demonstrate usage of $child, not necessary):

```
var fbRef = new Firebase('https://kato.firebaseio.com/users');
// $child gives a new $firebase object! not a ref to a hash key!
$firebase( fbRef ).$child( user_id ).$bind($scope, 'user');
```

If I wanted to access any of this data programmatically inside my controller, I could do it like so:

```
var fbRef = new Firebase('https://kato.firebaseio.com/users');
var usersRef = $firebase( fbRef );
var userId = 'kato';
usersRef.$on('loaded', function() {
   if( usersRef.hasOwnProperty(userId) ) {
      // note that we just grab it by key; not $child!
      var userRecord = usersRef[userId]; 
      console.log(userId + ' was found, name is ' + userRecord.name + ' and priority is ' + userRecord['$priority']);
   }

});
```

Comment: Sorry Kato - I spent a couple hours trying to recreate this but `myRef[blah]` and `myRef.blah` always return undefined.  `myRef.$child('blah')` works but is limited because like you said it can't return anything with a '$'. I don't know how much of that has to do with AngularFire, I'll take this over to their github and see what they say about the missing $priority.  But here's a feature request: `startAt(fbRef.getIndex()[100])` (Yes this is all about trying to startAt() the nth item in the firebase! The way mine is set up it's not so easy figuring out the $id and $priority) Thanks as always!