# How do you access loaded data from .$on('loaded') in AngularFire 0.5.0

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am having trouble accessing the data loaded from firebase using the .$on method in AngularFire 0.5.0

In the callback when I log out the contents of the scope the data is there but when I try to use deeper data I get `undefined`. Perhaps I am misunderstanding how you are meant to access data in this method?

This is my controller:

```
.controller('AssetDetailCtrl',
  ['$scope', '$firebase', 'FBURL',
  function($scope, $firebase, FBURL) {
    var refAsset = new Firebase(FBURL + '/assets/' + $scope.assetId);
    $scope.asset = $firebase(refAsset);

    // when data is loaded check validity of the route
    $scope.asset.$on('loaded', function() {
      console.log($scope.asset); // complete with the asset data
      console.log($scope.asset.name); // undefined even though it appears in the above console log
    });
}])
```

So perhaps there is a better way to do this.
Why is it I cannot access the data from the scope the even though it logs to the console?

This is the result of the first console.log

```
Object { $bind: function, $add: function, $save: function, $set: function, $remove: function…}
  $add: function (b,c){var d;return d="object"==typeof b?a._fRef.ref().push(a._parseObject(b),c):a._fRef.ref().push(b,c)}
  $bind: function (b,c){return a._bind(b,c)}
  $child: function (b){var c=new AngularFire(a._q,a._parse,a._timeout,a._fRef.ref().child(b));return c.construct()}
  $getIndex: function (){return angular.copy(a._index)}
  $on: function (b,c){switch(b){case"change":a._onChange.push(c);break;case"loaded":a._onLoaded.push(c);break;default:throw new Error("Invalid event type "+b+" specified")}}
  $remove: function (b){b?a._fRef.ref().child(b).remove():a._fRef.ref().remove()}
  $save: function (b){b?a._fRef.ref().child(b).set(a._parseObject(a._object[b])):a._fRef.ref().set(a._parseObject(a._object))}
  $set: function (b){a._fRef.ref().set(b)}
  asset_author: Object
  collections: Array[2]
  creator: "John Doe"
  desc: "a description of the asset"
  file: "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/3/"
  filesize: "28kb"
  filetype: "jpg"
  name: "Cycling"
  release: "12/12/2013"
  tags: "tag1, tag3"
  type: "Photography"
  __proto__: Object
```

Second console.log returns `undefined`

Comment: It's not possible for .name to exist in one of those console.logs and not the other, since they are called one after the other. Something else must be at work here. Are you sure it's not nested in a child object? That it's not something like `$scope.asset.???.name` instead? Also, seeing the output of the two console.logs may help to spot the problem.

Comment: Same issue here. I can do console.log($scope.asset.$add) which will return the function, but any object like name or filetype will return undefined!

Comment: I had same issue too. Now It works properly (firebase probably repaired its library).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on [Kato's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20598636/how-can-you-manage-invalid-references-in-angularfire-0-5-0) I have been able to solve this.
I was unaware the loaded event passed the raw data of the loaded asset, it is undocumented in the AngularFire docs.

It doesn't explain the odd behaviour I was having with console.log but it does solve the problem.

```
.controller('AssetDetailCtrl',
  ['$scope', '$firebase', 'FBURL',
  function($scope, $firebase, FBURL) {
    var refAsset = new Firebase(FBURL + '/assets/' + $scope.assetId);
    $scope.asset = $firebase(refAsset);

    // when data is loaded check validity of the route
    $scope.asset.$on('loaded', function(value) {
      console.log(value); // data loaded from Firebase
      console.log(value.name); // subset of the returned value
    });
}])
```

Comment: `console.log($scope.asset.$child('name'));` will probably return the object you were looking for.

Comment: I was having the same issue. $scope.myRef had a JSON object in it fully loaded that I could see in the console, but $scope.myRef.myData returned undefined. Using $on works to get the object. $child actually just returns an object of the same type as $scope.myRef, it'll still have $ methods attached to it and you still can't access the data directly with dot notation.

Comment: Unverified but i believe the scope is not yet populated when this event is fired? Also worth noting the scope is accessible as expected when the change event is fired `$scope.asset.$on('change', function() {})`

Answer (score 0):

Just for my own sake and others out there that may be having the same issue as i did, stumbling upon this question googling for the answer. My problem was that sometimes i was getting `undefined` as the value from the callback of `$on('loaded')`.

The way i solved it in the end was to use that event as a way of knowing when i could call the `resource.$getIndex()`, and the use the indexes returned from that to loop through the content and possibly store that in a new array to access the raw data.