# How can you manage invalid references in AngularFire 0.5.0

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

For clarity when I say invalid references I mean something like:
https://[appname].firebaseIO.com/assets/:id
Where the ID doesn't match an item in firebase

Previously I have been doing this by looking at the item in the scope and checking if it's empty but this new version of AngularFire attaches all its methods ($add, $bind, $child etc) even when there is no data to load so checking if the object in the scope is empty no longer works.

Is there a more correct way to do this or should I perhaps check for items in the object that aren't functions as an alternative way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 0.5, the `loaded` event returns the raw value, which should suit your needs here:

```
var fbRef = new Firebase(URL);
$firebase( fbRef ).$on('loaded', function(value) {
    if( value === null ) { console.log('no record at this path'); }
});
```