# Does angularfire 0.5.0 work with promises and if so how?

Tags: angularjs, angularfire

More specifically is it possible to do something like:

1. authenticate a user
2. based on that user.id access a profile
3. profile determines authorization
4. update private information

1.then(2 or err).then(3 or err).then(4 or err) is straight forward.

I know there is $on('loaded', function(){ [How do you access loaded data from .$on('loaded') in AngularFire 0.5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20597947/how-do-you-access-loaded-data-from-onloaded-in-angularfire-0-5-0) } unless it was already 'loaded' and still cached 
and $on('change', function(){}).
Something like:

```
$scope.$on('$firebaseAuth:login', function(){
    $scope.profile = $firebase(new..);
    $scope.profile.$on('loaded', function(data){
        if(data.authorized === true){
            $scope.private = $firebase(new..);
            $scope.private.$on('loaded', function(){
                var foo = $scope.private.$child('foo');
                foo = 'bar';
                $scope.private.$save('foo');
                $scope.private.someMethod(){..}
            })
        }
    })
})
```

This isn't considering errors and doesn't seem like the cleanest way to do things. Is it possible to use promises with or instead of $on events, and if so how? If not, what is the best approach to this case that would catch any errors along the way?

Comment: Support for promises in the authentication module for AngularFire had been added to 'master' on Github. There'll be a new version out soon that supports promises.

Comment: Thats great news, I like the returned objects with the important Firebase methods built in, and $bind is cool. The current version baffles me when trying to resolve $firebase references that depend on data from other asynch references.  Would it be practical to build a service to get me to the profile stage? This would allow me to begin constructing some basic authorization.

Comment: I'll try to build a custom promise that gets resolved on data.authorized === true, and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to create services that return promises, take care of establishing the firebase references, and handle the $q & $on('loaded') stuff. I found this [tutorial on chaining promises](https://github.com/ThomasBurleson/angularjs-FlightDashboard) to be helpful.

```
    .service('authorizeService',['$q', '$firebase',
    function($q, $firebase){
        "use strict";
        return{
            getIsAdmin: function(profile){
                var dfrd = $q.defer();
                var firef = $firebase(new Firebase('https://YOURFIREBASE.firebaseio.com/profiles/' + profile));

                firef.$on('loaded',function(data){
                    if(data === null){
                        dfrd.reject();
                    }else{
                        dfrd.resolve({
                            displayName: data.displayName,
                            isAdmin: data.isAdmin
                        });
                    }
                });
                return dfrd.promise;
            }
        }
    }])
.service('adminService',['$q',
    function($q){
    "use strict";
        return{
            getAdmin:function(admin){
                var dfrd = $q.defer();
                if(admin){
                    dfrd.resolve({
                        adminWidget: 'Behold... The Adminopacalypse.'
                    });
                }else{
                    dfrd.resolve({
                        adminWidget: 'You are not an admin.'
                    });
                }
                return dfrd.promise;
            }
        };
    }])
```

The controller contains functions that call those service methods attach values to the scope and return an object for the next promise in the chain. These were all wrapped in the $on('$firebase:login) to kick them off for each new login.

```
    .controller('qtest', ['$rootScope','$scope', 'userQService', 'authorizeService', 'adminService', '$firebaseAuth',
    function($rootScope,$scope, userQService, authorizeService, adminService, $firebaseAuth){
        "use strict";
        var loadAuthorizeAdmin = function(user){
            return authorizeService.getIsAdmin(user)
                .then(function(value){
                    $scope.isAdmin = value;
                    return value.isAdmin;
                });
        };
        var loadAdmin = function(isAdmin){
            return adminService.getAdmin(isAdmin)
                .then(function(value){
                    $scope.adminWidget = value;
                    return value.adminWidget;
                });
        };

        $rootScope.$on('$firebaseAuth:login',
            function(){
                var profile = $rootScope.auth.user.provider + '-' + $rootScope.auth.user.id;
                $scope.user = profile;
                loadAuthorizeAdmin(profile)
                    .then(loadAdmin);
                    //could be further chained
            });

        $rootScope.auth = $firebaseAuth(new Firebase('https://YOURFIREBASE.firebaseio.com'));
        $scope.loginOne = function(){
            $rootScope.auth.$login('password', {email: 'test@test.foo', password: 'test'});
        }
        $scope.loginTwo = function(){
            $rootScope.auth.$login('password', {email: 'test2@test2.foo', password: 'test2'});
        }

        $scope.logout = function(){
            $scope.user = null;
            $scope.isAdmin = null;
            $scope.adminWidget = null;
            $rootScope.auth.$logout();
        }
        $scope.user = null;
        $scope.isAdmin = null;
        $scope.adminWidget = null;
    }])
```

There is always a better approach but, this works. I didn't address errors but this is getting long.