# retrieve data from firebase (angularjs)

Tags: angularjs, view, controller, firebase

**UPDATE : find my answer here**
[A little clarity on getting key values using AngularFire v2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20597581/a-little-clarity-on-getting-key-values-using-angularfire-v2)

I looked for many sources before asking a simple question but Im just sarting with firebase and I can't manage to use the data the way I want. What I need, is to retrieve two int in my controller (how much "yes" and how much "no" linked to a question.

the data model is the following
question/id/(text, yes, no)

I have a service where I call my data using an id

```
app.service('QuestionService', function($firebase,$q) {
  var _this = this;
  //initialize Firebase
  var ref = new Firebase('https://basename.firebaseio.com/question');

  this.get = function(nb){
     var QuestionObject = ref.child(nb);
     return $firebase(QuestionObject);
  };

  return this;
});
```

I have a controller function where I call some data using a random id

```
$scope.pickQuestion = function(){
  var randomnumber = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 3);
  $scope.message = QuestionService.get(randomnumber);
};
```

and then it works great so I can have something like

```
{{message.yes}} or {{message.no}} and get the corresponding integer.
```

My issue, what I want to do, is to pass this "message.no" value to my controller. I don't know what to do. I can't manage to get the value directly inside the controller (it works only inside the view) and I can't manage to pass the value to my controller from the view. I tried a

```
 ng-init="functionName({{message.yes}}, {{message.no}})"
```

but it return an error into the console. (however the source a displayed correctly)

Does someone could guide me into the right direction?
Thanks

Comment: In ng-init the expression should be `functionName(message.yes, message.no)`

Comment: this is not working, the ng-init is marked like this "ng-init="ratio(message.yes, message.no)" in the source and the console.log I set in the controller function return undefined.

functionName(yes, no)
console.log(yes) ==> return "undefined"

Comment: are yes and no supposed to be values or objects? because message.no is trying to find the no method of the message object and that function doesn't exist.

Comment: values (integer) but I found a way to solve my problem using the link in the update. this allow to grab the data into the controller so there is no more issue playing with data.